# How to get class'es method without importing class

Tags: java, package, visibility

There is a situation:

package pak1 contains some class

```
package pak1;

public class A {
    public void g() {}
}
```

and another package pak2

```
package pak2;

public class B {    
    public  void f() {
       // here I want to call method g() from class A
    }
}
```

Is there any way to call class's `A` method `g()` without importing class `A` (and then `new A().g()`)?

If the method g() was static, I could write

```
public void f() {
    pak1.A.g();
}
```

Comment: Your question looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you describe why don't you want to use import?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use fully qualified class name like:

```
pak1.A a = new pak1.A();
a.g();
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no, you need to import it.

Having said this, you could still execute `A.g()` without importing if you use refection API. Keep in mind that would add unnecessary complexity to your code.

Comment: `new pak1.A().g()`  - no import.

Answer (score 0):

As you said its possible only for static imports but otherwise its not possible.

Example of static imports is below where assertEquals is method under Assert class

```
 import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found answer from SMA a bit confusing. Here is another way to write it that may help explain the syntax:

```
// Use Scanner.nextLine() without import

class InputClass {
    public static String getString() {
        String bob = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        return bob;
    }
}
```